# How to update a single value in a complex numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the (1, 2, 2) Python numpy array (X) below that needs to be updated by replacing a single value at a time. I am for instance looking to replace 0.54 with 0.99 while dropping [0.11, 0.45] at the same time. I am struggling with replacing it appropriately.

I am just showing one slice of X but it is a rather big one.

```
 array([[[0.11, 0.45],
        [0.33, 0.54]]])
```

to

```
array([[[0.33, 0.99]]])
```

This is what I tried.

```
X = np.append(X[:,1:,1:], [[[0.99]]], axis=1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't try to do those operations at the same time.  They are very different.

Comment: I have no idea how your described operations are related to your code, or what rules you are using to get from the input to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Just experimented a ton and here is how I am solving it now.

```
val = current value to input (0.99)
```

then

```
X[:,1:,1:] = val
```